# MySQL: Trigger PHP on Event

Tags: php, mysql, events, procedure

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following without using a cronjob/scheduled task that runs every x minute.

I have an event in the database that runs every 5 minutes and calls a procedure that checks a datetime column in a table to see if the datetime is greater then 30 days old and this is all working grand, what I want to happen here is when a date is greater then 30 days old that is kicks off an email to the relevant email address notifying them that the entry is 30 days old.

The slight catch to this is that as the website is already 95% built it has a built in notification class that handles all emails and has multi-lingual support based on the user being sent the email.

I know I can write a small PHP file to do all this and use a cronjob or windows scheduler to run it but I'm trying to stay away from relying on these features.

With all this is mind is there a way to tell MySQL to call/run a PHP file once the procedure finds a match after being run by the event in the event scheduler?

Comment: Out of curiousity why not use a cronjob?

Comment: I'm trying to keep as much reliance on 'external' features outside of MySQL and PHP where possible for ease of moving the site around/duplicating to different servers, if it's not possible obviously I will have to go down the cronjob route but I would prefer not to.

Comment: You could do it in a UDF written in C, that would use `system()` to execute the PHP script from the CLI.

Comment: The stuff you do using mysql event scheduler seems limited to db operations.  You could have your scheduled event write a row to an email table, but building and sending those emails would have to be triggered by cron or a php page visit (which might as well do the database operations at the same time).